# C++ Private variable not readable from secondary class

Tags: c++, class, variables, private, member

I have two classes, and in one of them i have a private variable. There is also a member function to change this variable and a get function to read it. Such class could look like this.

```
class Toggler {
public:
   void change()
   {
      randomBool = !randomBool;
   }

   bool getBool()
   {
   return randomBool;
private:
   bool randomBool = false;
};
```

Another function could now try to read the state of this boolean using the getBool() function. Could look something like this:

```
class Reader {
public:
   void printer()
   {
      Toggler toggler;
      cout << toggler.getBool() << endl;
   }
};
```

Now if i finally run all of those functions from my main class likes this:

```
Reader reader;
Toggler toggler;

cout << toggler.getBool() << endl;
reader.printer();

toggler.change();

cout << toggler.getBool() << endl;
reader.printer();
```

This will then output 0, 0, 1, 0.
The problem here is that the direct function toggler.getBool() gives me the correct value, however if i run the same function through another function in a seperate class i do not get the same result.

Comment: So, what result do you get when running through a separate class? You do realise that the `Toggler` in `class Reader` is recreated every time you call `printer()` and is completely independent from the `Toggler toggler:` in your main class? I cannot really follow exactly what your problem is...

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `getBool()` method in your `Reader` instance, you are actually doing so on a temporary local object rather than the instance in your main class. The `Toggler` instance in your main is not being referenced from inside `reader` as it has no direct reference to that instance.

If `Reader` needs to access a specific `Toggler` instance, you will need to pass it as a parameter, possibly to the `printer` function.

```
class Reader {
public:
   void printer(Toggler& toggler)
   {
      cout << toggler.getBool() << endl;
   }
};
```

Passing by reference avoids a copy.

Comment: Ahh, i see. How would i go about "fixing" this. My actual project requires it to be in seperate classes and i just made this example for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks alot Mikel!

Answer (score 2):

The variable `Toggler toggler;` inside the function in`class Reader` and the variable `Toggler toggler;` in your `main` are unrelated. They have the same name, but no connection.
You are changing one and then printing the other; of course you don't see any effect.

Comment: Ahh, i see. How would i go about "fixing" this. My actual project requires it to be in seperate classes and i just made this example for simplicity.

Comment: Move the variable from the function in the class scope and add a change method, or (probably better) pass main's variable through to the function call, as a reference parameter.